# Creating Sharepoint sublist for each object on the main list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-form

In sharepoint I want to make a list of problems to be solved in which there will be 5 columns. Each problem should have several tasks to solve it, in the form of a separate sublist with separate columns. Am I able to achieve something like this without having to download additional apps, just pure sharepoint. Below is what I would like it to look like

[image]

The sublist for each problem would look identical (same list of columns)

I found video that shows exactly what i want but he use lightning forms and i want pure sp..

[image]